# Reading between keywords in file, skipping lines, using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python to parse some data output from a programme into a text file. I need to:

- Search through the output file for a keyword
- Read the data after this keyword
- Stop reading at the END keyword

My issue is that I also need to skip out 'header lines' in the file when I read the data between the keywords. So in the example below I want to start reading at BETA, totally ignore any lines starting with "GROUP", ignore VELOCITY (m/s), and just extract the raw data, finishing at END.

```
    BETA 
   
    GROUP              1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8
    VELOCITY (m/s)    59.4604E+06   55.5297E+06   52.4463E+06   49.3329E+06   45.4639E+06   41.6928E+06   37.7252E+06   34.9447E+06
    
    GROUP              9            10            11            12            13            14            15            16
    VELOCITY (m/s)    33.2405E+06   30.8868E+06   27.9475E+06   25.2880E+06   22.8815E+06   21.1951E+06   20.1614E+06   18.7338E+06
    
    GROUP             17            18            19            20            21            22            23            24
    VELOCITY (m/s)    16.9510E+06   15.7017E+06   14.9359E+06   14.2075E+06   13.5146E+06   12.8555E+06   11.6805E+06   10.5252E+06
    
    GROUP             25            26            27            28            29            30            31            32
    VELOCITY (m/s)    10.0118E+06    9.5236E+06    9.0591E+06    8.2311E+06    7.4170E+06    7.0552E+06    6.4104E+06    5.4008E+06

    END
```

What I have so far is this:

```
main_identifier = "BETA"
start_identifier = "VELOCITY (m/s)"
end_identifier = "END"

def read_data_from_file_beta(file_name, main_identifier, start_identifier, end_identifier):
    list_of_results = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
            t=f.read()
            t=t[t.find(main_identifier):]
            t=t[t.find(start_identifier)+len(start_identifier):t.find(end_identifier)]
            t=t.replace('\n', ' ').split()
            t=[float(i) for i in t if not i.isidentifier()]
            list_of_results.extend(t)
    return(list_of_results)
```

This currently reads the whole of the section between the start and end identifiers, so it needs to be modified to skip out the unwanted lines. Right now I get the error message:

```
data=[float(i) for i in data if not i.isidentifier()]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(m/s)'
```

So it is getting confused when it arrives at the second line and reads the "(m/s)". How can I extract only the data I need?

Comment: Maybe some basic if condition for `i` could solve your problem? Try `if isinstance(i, float): t=[float(i) for i in t if not i.isidentifier()]`

Comment: Do you just want the numbers in all the lines that start with "VELOCITY (m/s)"?  In that case to other stuff doesn't matter (i.e. BETA, Group, END).

Comment: In this instance I only want the lines that start with VELOCITY, but I need to use this code multiple times for data from different sections which will have different keywords so I need a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks to me like the type of problem `regex` was invented for.

Here's my current solution:

```py
>>> import re
>>> text = """
...     BETA
...
...     GROUP              1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8
...     VELOCITY (m/s)    59.4604E+06   55.5297E+06   52.4463E+06   49.3329E+06   45.4639E+06   41.6928E+06   37.7252E+06   34.9447E+06
...
...     GROUP              9            10            11            12            13            14            15            16
...     VELOCITY (m/s)    33.2405E+06   30.8868E+06   27.9475E+06   25.2880E+06   22.8815E+06   21.1951E+06   20.1614E+06   18.7338E+06
...
...     GROUP             17            18            19            20            21            22            23            24
...     VELOCITY (m/s)    16.9510E+06   15.7017E+06   14.9359E+06   14.2075E+06   13.5146E+06   12.8555E+06   11.6805E+06   10.5252E+06
...
...     GROUP             25            26            27            28            29            30            31            32
...     VELOCITY (m/s)    10.0118E+06    9.5236E+06    9.0591E+06    8.2311E+06    7.4170E+06    7.0552E+06    6.4104E+06    5.4008E+06
...
...     END
... """
>>> # See this link for regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/vaHjVd/1
>>> regex = r"VELOCITY \(m\/s\)\s(.*)"
>>> re.findall(regex, text)
['   59.4604E+06   55.5297E+06   52.4463E+06   49.3329E+06   45.4639E+06   41.6928E+06   37.7252E+06   34.9447E+06', '   33.2405E+06   30.8868E+06   27.9475E+06   25.2880E+06   22.8815E+06   21.1951E+06   20.1614E+06   18.7338E+06', '   16.9510E+06   15.7017E+06   14.9359E+06   14.2075E+06   13.5146E+06   12.8555E+06   11.6805E+06   10.5252E+06', '   10.0118E+06    9.5236E+06    9.0591E+06    8.2311E+06    7.4170E+06    7.0552E+06    6.4104E+06    5.4008E+06']
```

Feel free to read up on other regex methods available on the standard library. For example you'd use [`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) if you want to iterate through each match, this would make the solution more memory efficient.

If you'd prefer you can also go line by line like so:

```py
for line in text.splitlines():
    # text is now ['','BETA', 'GROUP 1...', (etc)]
    m = re.search(regex, line)
    if m is not None:
        print(m)
```

Notice that I used `splitlines` instead of just iterating through the string, as that would have iterated through the string `char` by `char`; which is rarely what we want

I'd recommend that you play around a bit with Python's REPL (what you get by just calling python3 from the command line, see the `>>>`) and to manipulate your data until you can get what you'd like.

```py
>>> # Remove whitespace
>>> [s.split() for s in res]
[['59.4604E+06', '55.5297E+06', ...]
>>> # Flatten the list
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([s.split() for s in res]))
['59.4604E+06', '55.5297E+06', '52.4463E+06', '49.3329E+06', ... ]
```

Comment: Although this looks like exactly what I need, it doesn't work for me? I am just getting an empty list - I am using Python3 if this makes a difference?

Comment: I'm also using python3; it seems to me like your `text` variable is not cooperating. I'll edit my answer to show off how I setup my text.

Comment: So it's working now, thank you! The only thing is it is reading in each line of values as a single element, whereas I need each value separated. Can I make regex do this?

Comment: Of course, regex is quite powerful. But I would recommend you go for a simpler solution: `str(match).split('<number of spaces or tabs>')`. I can update my answer in a bit

Comment: Thanks! I also have the issue that the number of spaces or tabs between each number isn't always constant...

Comment: Calling `str.split()` will get rid of all white space :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will get list of list.

```
import re

group_data = []
velocity_data = []
with open("new_file") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "GROUP" in line:
            group_list = line.split()[1:]
            group_list = [int(i) for i in group_list]
            group_data.append(group_list)
        if "VELOCITY" in line:
            velo_list = line.split()[2:]
            velo_list = [float(i) for i in line.split()[2:]]
            velocity_data.append(velo_list)
```

velocity_data

```
[[59460400.0, 55529700.0, 52446300.0, 49332900.0, 45463900.0, 41692800.0, 37725200.0, 34944700.0], [33240500.0, 30886800.0, 27947500.0, 25288000.0, 22881500.0, 21195100.0, 20161400.0, 18733800.0], [16951000.0, 15701700.0, 14935900.0, 14207500.0, 13514600.0, 12855500.0, 11680500.0, 10525200.0], [10011800.0, 9523600.0, 9059100.0, 8231100.0, 7417000.0, 7055200.0, 6410400.0, 5400800.0]]
```

group_data

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]]
```

Comment: He doesn't need `group_data`.